# Android QuickBlox call

Tags: java, android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I'm trying to integrate QuickBlox for audio and video calls.
I followed tutorial but it doesn't work.
To enable an ability of receiving incoming WebRTC calls need add signalling manager but method

```
    public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally)
```

doesn't call. What is wrong?
jniLibs and permissions added
build: added dependency

```
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.3.0'
```

Here code:

```
private EditText mUsername;
private EditText mPassword;
private Button mSignUp;
private Button mSignIn;
private Button mCall;
private QBUser mUser;


QBRTCClient client;
QBSessionManager sessionManager;
QBChatService chatService;
QBRTCSession qbrtcSession;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);

    mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
    mSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    mCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_call);
    client = QBRTCClient.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

    QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
    QBChatService.setDefaultAutoSendPresenceInterval(60);
    chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();

    mSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mUser = new QBUser(mUsername.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString());
           // QBUsers.signIn(mUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            QBAuth.createSession(mUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBSession qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "My user: " + mUser);
                    Log.d(TAG, "received user: " + qbUser);
                    Log.d(TAG, "user logged in");
                    mUser.setId(qbUser.getUserId());

                    chatService.login(mUser, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "user logged in to the chat");
                            client.prepareToProcessCalls();
                            chatService.getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager().addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "created locally: " + createdLocally);
                                    if (!createdLocally) {
                                        client.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

This line never call:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "created locally: " + createdLocally);
```

Answer (score 0):

the method signalingCreated() is called when you make a call or when you get a call. You can look at [video sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc) it works all ok. BTW, you don't need to manage session manually and there is no need to call createSession methods. Just use QBUsers.signIn(). [Documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android#SDK_3.2.0_Authentication).

Comment: I have already found solution but thanks anyway. About QBUser you shouldn't even signIn, enough create new QBUser with id and password